# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2014 System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll Error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, .net-2.0, sql-server-2014, .net-4.6

SSMS 2014 SP1 recently started throwing an error around a mismatch of the System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll when trying to connect to any database.

I had recently installed LinqPad 5 which required installing.Net 4.6.

Trying to repair SSMS did not fix the issue.  Various resources online, suggesting updating the GAC and `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_System.EnterpriseServices_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_2.0.0.0_x-ww_7d5f3790` assemblies from the .Net 2.0 folder and the  also did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to get my dev environment back to working as normal.  Obviously it isn't ideal, so if anyone has a better solution, please share.

As an interim measure:

- Uninstall .Net 4.6 from Add/Remove Programs
- Reinstall .Net 4.5.1
  from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh487283.aspx
- Restart SSMS, possibly you may need to restart your computer

If you subsequently recieve an error in Visual Studio:

- Open the VS developer command prompt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts for Visual Studio 2013)
- Run devenv /setup
- Alternatively you could run a repair from the VS installer

I believe this is because .Net 4.6 overwrites the files in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` folder, as .Net 4.x all share this folder, SSMS doesn't seem to be able to handle the updgrade.  .Net 2.0 uses a different folder, hence why alot of the solutions around presumably didn't help.

Comment: As I said, this isn't an ideal fix.  But this may help someone in the mean time.

I was hunting though lot's of similar questions in the mean time and it seems like this could be a generic issue.